# getting max and min of five input from user more than one time

Tags: java, class, methods, max, min

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Compare
{
    Integer max;
    Integer min;

    public void max(int num)
    {
        if (max == null)
            max = num;
        else if(num > max)
            max = num;
    }

    public void min(int num)
    {
        if (min == null)
            min = num;
        else if(num < min)
            min = num;
    }
}
class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Compare compare = new Compare();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int sets = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < sets ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                int num_main = input.nextInt();
                compare.max(num_main);
                compare.min(num_main);
            }
            System.out.println(compare.max);
            System.out.println(compare.min);
        }
    }
}
```

> I want to calculate max and min of five inputs from the user, i managed to get max value and min value but if i test two groups i dont get the correct max value instead i am getting the previous max value as my max value. How can i get the max value in the simplest possible way

Comment: Think about `infinite loops` and conditions that will make it terminate.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest change is to move the `compare` inside the first loop, so it finds the new `max` (and `min`) each time a new "`set`" of numbers is entered.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sets ; i++)
{
    Compare compare = new Compare();
    //...
    //as you were     
}
```

When you make a `compare` before this loop it will keep hold of the values over each set of numbers entered.
You want it to find the `max` and `min` *per* set of numbers entered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restore your `compare` object before move to next loop. Modify a bit in your code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sets ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            int num_main = input.nextInt();
            compare.max(num_main);
            compare.min(num_main);
        }
        System.out.println(compare.max);
        System.out.println(compare.min);
        compare = new Compare();
    }
```

Explain: 
Assume that `sets = 2`:
After having gotten 5 user input, you get max and min. Before move to second loop, you must restore your `compare` object before getting 5 next user inputs as above code. you also can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sets ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        int num_main = input.nextInt();
        compare.max(num_main);
        compare.min(num_main);
    }
    System.out.println(compare.max);
    System.out.println(compare.min);
    compare.max = compare.min = null;
}
```